# Perché si dice "fatti vedere" e non "fatti visto"?

Tags: word-usage

Nell'espressione "fatti vedere" che si traduce in inglese "let me see you", non riesco a comprendere perché la parola "vedere" è all'infinito e non al participio passato ("fatti *visto*"?).

Comment: Perché mai dovrebbe essere *“fatti visto”? Anche in inglese non è *_let me seen you_. Pensalo come _allow me to see you_, se ti aiuta.

Comment: @DaG Ma dice *fat**ti*** non *far**mi***. i.e. è "farmi vederti" ma "fatJti visto (da me)" (sono *me* che sono fatto di **veder**ti, ma sei *te* che sei fatto **visto**). In inglese *make yourself **seen***.

Comment: @DaG Una risposta a questa domanda potrebbe elaborare sull'uso modale di *fare* e su come questo sia diverso da *lasciare* e *permettere* (e.g. una traduzione più letterale di *let me see you* è *lasciami vederti*). Credo sia una cosa ovvia per i parlanti nativi ma che possa confondere coloro che vengono da una lingua diversa (in particolare non romanza)

Comment: @iBug Non sono sicuro di aver capito bene il tuo ragionamento. Ora cerco di spiegarmi meglio in una risposta.

Comment: Giusto, @DenisNardin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La prima cosa da chiarire è probabilmente questo uso del verbo “fare”. È un verbo con moltissimi usi e significati diversi, come si può vedere già solo dalla lunghezza della [voce “fare”](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/fare2) su un vocabolario.

Quello che ci interessa qui è quello che nella voce del Treccani è al punto 4.a:

> 4. Può avere valore causativo, in diverse costruzioni: a. Con un infinito: *far fare*, ordinare (o provocare) che si faccia: *l’ho fatto andar via*; *fammi lavorare in pace*, lasciami, ecc.; ma anche indurre, costringere: *E me che i tempi ed il desio d’onore Fan per diversa gente ir fuggitivo* (Foscolo); *non mi far dire*; *mi farai perdere la pazienza*, ecc.

Prendiamo l'esempio “l'ho fatto andar via”: significa più o meno “gli ho ordinato di andare via” oppure “ho fatto in modo che andasse via” (in inglese è forse *I made him leave*).

Il modo in cui si costruisce il verbo “fare” per questo tipo di frase è:

> soggetto + verbo “fare” + infinito del verbo che descrive che cosa si ordina + complemento oggetto

Per esempio: “L'ufficiale fa marciare i soldati”. Il soggetto può essere sottinteso: “Faccio marciare i soldati”. (L'ordine delle parole può variare, specialmente se il complemento oggetto è un pronome: “L'ufficiale li fa marciare”.)

Se il verbo principale fosse all'imperativo (se, per esempio, in quest'ultima frase, un ufficiale superiore desse un ordine a uno inferiore) la frase potrebbe essere: “Falli marciare”. Cioè, *“Fa' marciare loro”, ma in qualsiasi frase di questo tipo – indipendentemente dal fatto che c'è il verbo “fare” – il complemento oggetto viene espresso da un pronome enclitico, cioè che si unisce al verbo. Per esempio, non si dice *“Mangia esso” o *“Mangia lui”, bensì “Mangialo”; non si dice *“Guarda loro”, ma “Guardali”.

Siamo quasi arrivati alla tua frase (“Fatti vedere”). Così come un ufficiale dice a un altro “Falli marciare”, tu puoi dire a una persona con un vestito nuovo “Fatti vedere” (che è la forma con il pronome enclitico di *“Fa' vedere te (stesso)”). Forse è più comprensibile se al posto di “far vedere” metti un verbo unico di significato simile, come “mostrare”: in questo caso diremmo “mostrati” (cioè *“mostra te”).

Quindi anche in questo caso chiediamo o ordiniamo a qualcuno di compiere una certa azione, come se fosse “Fa' vedere il libro alla mamma”. Qui al posto del libro c'è “te”, che diventa il pronome enclitico “-ti”, e al posto di “alla mamma” c'è “a me” o a qualcun altro, che però è sottinteso.